# Cannot login in graphical interface

Tags: 15.04, xorg

I have a problem with Ubuntu. I can't log in within LightDM, because when I enter password, Unity starts loading and then it returns right to login screen, and the desktop won't start.

Note: I use home folder for that user from previous installation

Edit: I chowned .Xauthority and still nothing
When I try startx, there are some noveau messages (HUB0, GPC0 and hex numbers)
Edit2: guest session works and newly created user also works

Comment: Please write an answer how your problem has been solved or delete the question.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a GPU related problem.

Install the current stable NVIDIA driver :

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-current
sudo reboot
```

If this driver doesn't work, replace the driver.

Install the latest current stable NVIDIA driver
from the NVIDIA short-lived branch (355.11) :

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-355
sudo reboot
```

Comment: Thank you very mush for your answer, but it was just privilege issue :)

Comment: @David8 : I suggest that you install NVIDIA drivers anyway because your problem may return randomly. I know several similar cases like yours and all of them were permanently resolved after NVIDIA driver was installed !

Answer (score 1):

I did `chown <user> * -R`, deleted `.Xauthority` and `.ICEauthority` in my home folder and it was pretty much solved